# How to install the latest version of microtype (v. 2.5) in Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu, microtype

How to install the latest version of microtype (v. 2.5) in Linux (Ubuntu) ?

(also, is v. 2.5 still in beta?)

**Edit**

I'm using this ppa https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa/ which currently delivers `2012.20120611-3~ubuntu12.04.1`, where `texlive-latex-recommended` contains **`microtype`** (v. 2.4).

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/letterspace.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.lua
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-bch.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-blg.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-euf.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-eur.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-euroitc.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-eus.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-mvs.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-pad.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-pmn.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ppl.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ptm.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-ugm.cfg
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-zpeu.cfg
```

Comment: No, `microtype` 2.5 is not beta any more. What TeX distribution are you using? The Debian supplied 2009 or 2012?

Comment: Just two shots in the dark: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) and [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I saw your question on one of my older questions.  Egreg provided excellent details so I'll just use his instructions:
Create a directory for microtype in your local TeX path.

```
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/microtype
```

Then move all the microtype stuff into that folder.

Next you need to tell TeX to use the new version you've installed:

```
sudo texhash
```

Now you have the most recent version of microtype installed locally. Your old microtype installation will still be on your system but LaTeX will know to look at this local installation first.

Comment: I updated my question; does your answer still apply?

Comment: I think the command should be: `mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/microtype`

Comment: Be aware that your local version of microtype will always be preferred over any future version of microtype installed by your distribution.

Comment: Nutty, right now you have 2.4 installed, do you really need 2.5?  If so then it looks like you're going to have to install it yourself. My answer allows you to install the latest microtype package manually instead of using what's in the repository since it might not always be current. You download the package from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) and then install it as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, here on Fedora 18 (ships TeXlive 2012) it is just a `dnf install "tex(microtype.sty)"` (or `yum`, if you cling to that) away.

Comment: I updated my question; does your answer still apply?