# Is microtype compatible (and effective) with a font like Calibri?

Tags: fonts, microtype

Is [microtype](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) compatible (and effective) with a font like [Calibri](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96993/how-to-use-the-calibri-font) ?

*For details on microtype, see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82001/microtype-settings-for-dummies) and [here](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/microtype/).*

---

**Edit**

- With "**compatible**" I mean **error-message-free**.
- With "**effective**" I mean that one would see a markedly positive difference when using `microtype`: that it **just looks** a lot **better**!

Comment: Your question is a bit vague: What do you mean by "compatible" and/or "effective"? Do you use XeTeX or LuaTeX? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico So far I'm using neither `XeTeX` nor `LuaTeX` (or `Calibri` in `TeX`, for that matter) and have only used `microtype` with `pdflatex` (with `Computer Modern`).

Comment: @Mico With "compatible" I mean error-msg-free and with "effective" I mean that one would see a markedly positive difference when using `microtype`: that it just looks a lot better!

Comment: I don’t have Calibri, but I’ve used many fonts for which no `.cfg` file is supplied, and yes, `microtype` still produces more pleasing output.  And you can write your own configuration file if you have the patience.

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks for your vote of confidence! Just had a quick glance at [font configuration](http://latex-project.org/guides/cfgguide.pdf) which seems pretty involved; I hope `microtype` & `Calibri` will just look smashing by default -- even without taking a look beneath the bonnet...

Comment: *That* configuration guide is involved.  I meant the configuration described in section 5.7 of the `microtype` manual.  Use the files in `/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype` (or wherever they dwell on your system) as models.  Nothing needed except — hah! — a very good eye, time, and abundant patience.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty -- you've provided an explanation in your comments for "what you mean".  if you edit this explanation into the question, it will improve the question.  (and probably save it from being closed.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Added the comment to the question; only today am I finding the time to attempt an MWE: the MWE will probably answer the question...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, `microtype` will never issue an error message when it encounters a font that it doesn't know about, so it is always "compatible" in your sense.

With regards to "effective": For *protrusion* of unknown fonts (Calibri being one of them), `microtype` will use fallback settings and write an info about this in the log file. These fallback settings (in `microtype.cfg`) are quite conservative and contain protrusion settings only for the characters which are most likely to require protrusion (but this is still more than what the settings from `luaotfload` contain, which actually only protrude the punctuation characters). This should give reasonable results in most cases. Of course, it is possible, and probably preferable, to create a proper configuration file for the font in question, but this requires some time and a good eye.

With *expansion* the situation is even better, as it doesn't require dedicated font settings, and will just work, even for unknown fonts.

Comment: Where does `luaotfload` come into play? When using Lua's `Microtype` feature? -- Also, why is there *no* change in vector/pixel what-so-ever [in here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122078/27721) ?

Comment: `luaotfload` is the package that provides the protrusion and expansion features you activate via `\newfontfeature` (it is loaded by `fontspec`). As to why there is no change for you with the `microtype` package, I don't know, there certainly is for me, and for @bfootdav as well. That's why I asked whether you are using the latest version of `microtype`.

Comment: I guess [I'm still on v. 2.4](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105779/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-microtype-v-2-5-in-linux-ubuntu). Could that be the explanation for having **no effect** (for me / my installation) with `Calibri`?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty That will be the explanation -- support for luatex and xetex came with v2.5. Can you not update (e.g. by installing TeX Live 2013)?

Comment: As explained in the link given my previous comment, I'm using the latest available ppa (for Ubuntu) and wouldn't like to do manual installs, unless I find a compelling reason to do so. Would you say `\lipsum` looks a lot better with `microtype` *vs.* `Microtype` (in your more updated installation), or are they more or less on par? I can see a clear/dominant improvement using `Microtype` (as opposed to not using *any* micro-typing..) already; would it still get that much better using `microtype` (which I've gratefully used in a longer, recent `Computer Modern` document compiled with `pdftex`) ?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Depends on how demanding you are. As I said in my answer, the `luatex` solution will only protrude punctuation characters (comma, period, (semi)colon, hyphens and dashes), whereas `microtype` will also protrude other characters like, e.g. "A" and "«". For expansion, there won't be much difference. So, as the improvement only lies in the details, you might as well wait until you can easily update your TeX installation.

Answer (score 2):

Using `LuaLateX`, default settings (default *.cfg, see `microtype` manual):

- compatible: **yes**
- effective: **no**.

No as in *no change*, not even on the sub-pixel level.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit**

Even / also tried with the [`Asap` font family (free, open, ..)](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/asap) which is v much like `Calibri`: same here, `\usepackage{microtype}` alone has **zero** effect.

---

**Edit 2**

*Nota bene:*

- *No* <strike>effect</strike> [in **`microtype` v.2.4**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105779/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-microtype-v-2-5-in-linux-ubuntu), but apparently ***does*** have an effect in later versions (v.**2.5** and above).

Comment: That's odd. I don't have Calibri but I just downloaded Asap and I got noticeable differences with both protrusion and font expansion. You might try using `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Asap-Regular}`as I did notice that it wasn't using ligatures or even proper quotation marks by default.  
Also, I used Lualatex, what engine did you use?

Comment: Are you using the latest `microtype` version (v2.5a)?

Comment: @Robert No... (see my comment to your question below)

Comment: @bfootdav I guess you're using version **2.5** then? See my updated answer: **Edit 2**.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Yep, 2.5a. You can upgrade to the latest version if you want and it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Robert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82637/27721), this is a viable workaround using LuaLateX's own `Microtype` implementation (note the capital `M`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Calibri}

% \usepackage{microtype}

\pdfprotrudechars=2
\pdfadjustspacing=2
\newfontfeature{Microtype}{protrusion=default;expansion=default;}
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=.5}
\setmainfont[Microtype,
             Numbers={OldStyle, Proportional},
             Ligatures=TeX
            ]{Calibri}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This, unlike `microtype`, **does** have an immediate (and positive !) effect.

:-)